# Adding /etc/hosts entry to host machine on vagrant up

Tags: vagrant

Is it possible for one to modify files on the host machine during the `vagrant up` process? For example, adding an entry to the host machine's `/etc/hosts` file to avoid having to do this manually?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The solution is to use [`vagrant-hostsupdater`](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater)

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater
```

> This plugin adds an entry to your /etc/hosts file on the host system.
>
> On up and reload commands, it tries to add the information, if its not
>   already existant in your hosts file. If it needs to be added, you will
>   be asked for an administrator password, since it uses sudo to edit the
>   file.
>
> On halt, suspend and destroy, those entries will be removed again.

Comment: That plugin is also not vagrant 1.1+ compatible as far as I am aware (I used to use it) and it will only set host names for the vm's ip... if you need to add entries for other ip's then you probably better off using the shell provisioner.

Comment: consider https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager instead. It does basically same thing but has decent windows support, and also can manage guest hosts file.

Answer (score 5):

OK, so now the guy sitting next to you at the coffee shop can most likely <strike>ssh to port 2222</strike> (EDIT: changed on newer versions of vagrant, unless you explicitly enable external access) on your computer, login as vagrant with the insecure key, modify your Vagrantfile, since it's mounted read-write and owned by the vagrant user, insert arbitrary ruby code to run in the host environment,  and now it looks like they've got root access on the host environment as well.  Brilliant.

I hope people run firewalls on their development machines.

EDIT:

So after writing the above, I bugged the author of Vagrant, the default has been changed so that port 2222 is not open by default on the external interface.  Big improvement (though still something to be careful of, since external access is often opened up for various reasons).

So, having put in effort to get the situation fixed since making this comment, I'm now getting down votes, apparently because the comment is out of date.  Damn.  It was correct when written.

EDIT:

In response to Steve Buzonas, the point is that if there's any likelhihood of the virtual machine being compromised then giving the `vagrant up` process elevated permissions represents a serious risk to the security of the host environment, and also being able to modify the /etc/hosts environment file is dangerous, even without general root access.  As I've pointed out, vagrant's approach to keeping the VM secure is not particularly rigorous.

Comment: this is helpful although the tone is hostile

Comment: @jayunit100: That's kind of fair comment, but I'm more than a little exasperated by the attitude of the vagrant developer, who having had these problems pointed out is very reluctant to actually fix stuff, or to add appropriate warnings to his software.  Stuff like what's proposed here makes it worse, and needs to be very clearly signposted as dangerous.

Comment: I'm so gonna hang out in coffee shops to try this.

Comment: Vagrant's 2222 port is bound to localhost. How are you going to do a remote login on that ? `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2222          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`your point is moot

Comment: Vagrant's 2222 port is bound to localhost only  since version 1.2.3  so this WAS an issue to be more precise

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. The only thing it has in common is they both involve vagrant. To address the issue you mention a good skeleton vagrant file should provision ssh to disallow password login and replace authorized keys file with either a randomly generated key or the current user's public key.

Comment: @Steve Buzonas I've edited my answer to clarify that the connection is that because of the insecurities of vagrant, it's a bad idea to pursue the solution the OP sought.

Comment: I would like to point out, since mc0e has not run the plugin before writing this diatribe, that the plugin clearly states what it's going to do and then asks for your system password to do it. Vagrant up does not remember your password or ask for it by default. Of course it could be lying, but that's the point of being screwed by "untrusted code" and would ultimately lead to you never downloading anything that wasn't provided with your computer when you bought it, and maybe never running JS in browser either.

Comment: @LouisSt-Amour That's sort of true. I could routinely reject requests for the system password, or I could make a practice of checking the contents of the vagrant folder for new security issues every time before running vagrant.  Either way, I can't see this plugin reducing my workload.  Regarding 'untrusted code', note that if I trust vagrant and this plugin, I should not need to also trust that what happens inside the VM cannot compromise the host environment.

Comment: @mc0e, if you think the issue with VMs lies with Vagrant, you're sorely mistaken. People have been raising issues with VMs for years: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/how-secure-are-virtual-machines-really-false-sense-of-security -- Ultimately this comes down to the "security-vs-functionality" debate that has no right answer, except that people tend to trade some amount of security for some amount of additional functionality. And if you're that paranoid about changes, I could suggest running tripwire -- http://www.tripwire.org

Comment: @LouisSt-Amour, Enough said.  People can draw their own conclusions.

Comment: Curiously, while this answer has gotten negative votes over-all, it's also received more positive votes than any other answer I've put on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to depend on some plug in to vagrant. It should be standard feature  in Vagrant!!!! Untill then I use a shell script to propagate VM's in my cluster of new VMs. The key lines are :

```
# Obtain the hostkey based on the IP-address and add it to the known_host list 
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa ${START}.${OFFSET} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts

# obtain the hostname, because you might not know it yet, with the IP address:
EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME=`ssh ${START}'.'${OFFSET} 'hostname'`
# obtain the key ot the new other VM based on hostname and also add to known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa ${EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME} >>  /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts
# so now you have the IP address and the corresponding hostname
# add to /etc/hosts without being asked for "yes/no"
echo  ${START}'.'${OFFSET}' '${EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME} >> /etc/hosts
```

Where IPADRRESS is the IP address of the master VM in the cluster with several slave node VM's with succeedding ip-addresses. (IPADDRESS=IPADDRESS + 1 untill no successfull ping)

```
IPADDRESS=`ip addr show eth1 | grep 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cut -d '/' -f1`
START=`echo ${IPADDRESS} | cut -d '.' -f1,2,3`
OFFSET=`echo ${IPADDRESS} | cut -d '.' -f4`
```

And then I loop trough the next IP addresses until no more succesfull pings.
I do not want to hardcode anything (ip-address or hostname), but to find out itself.

Resulting /etc/hosts file (after 
    sort /etc/hosts | uniq > /tmp/hosts.uniq && sudo sh -c 'mv /tmp/hosts.uniq /etc/hosts'
:

```
[vagrant@master ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.0.1       master.RHEL70.local     master
192.168.1.50 master.RHEL70.local
192.168.1.51 node01.RHEL70.local
192.168.1.52 node02.RHEL70.local
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Answer (score -2):

Previously I didn't know how to vagrant edit my etc/host file. But when i reinstalled window and vagrant, this feature disappeared.