# Vagrant: Automating edit of config files - standard approach?

Tags: configuration, insert, automation, edit, vagrant

For example I want to automate the adding of a SAMBA share by adding a share "block" `/etc/samba/smb.conf` (if it is not already present), as in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16624958/227926

...rather than have to manually edit this file.

I'd want it to detect if the block was already present too.

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Shell provisioner in the `Vagrantfile` may be the easiest way.

See: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html

Use either inline (here document) or an external shell script in `Vagrantfile`, to check if the block exists (e.g. use grep/ack/ag etc and check the return value `$?`), if NOT, add it to the `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 Thanks @Terry Wang - I think this looks like the definitive thing to try given that it comes from the same 'stable' as Vagrant itself.

Comment: Another option is: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/ajjahn/samba - thanks to associate Mike Bell for this suggestion.